# Show data inside a panel in the same line

Tags: asp.net, panel

I have a panel inside which im showing some data... the problem now is when i run it the other data is applearing in another line

```
 <asp:Panel ID="PanelContainer" runat="server" Width="100%" >
 <asp:Panel ID="PanelHeaderList" runat="server" Width="15px" Height="15px">
                                    <div style="float:left;" >
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ico/expand.png" AlternateText="Expand or Collapse"/>
                                    </div>
                                     </asp:Panel>
                                    <div style="float:left;width:80%;" >       
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxSelect" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="GroupCheckChanged" />            
                                    <asp:Label ID="Grp_NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Grp_Name") %>' />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfGrpID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Grp_ID") %>' />
                                    </div>
            </asp:Panel>
```

Now in this I need to show the Image, checkbox and data in the same line.. how can i acheive this??

Answer (score 1):

Remember what html element a panel generates, and how you can always alter this using the [`CssClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) attribute and a custom stylesheet.

So, if you wanted to style your panel to be an element that floats left (retaining the single-line appearance) you could:

```
.single-line-panel { display: inline-block; float: left; }

<asp:Panel CssClass="single-line-panel" ...> ... </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: It dint worked. must have to try some thing other. Im using that panel for Ajax COllapsible panel. maybe because of that.